# Filesystem best practices

Tags: magento2, coding-standards, filesystem

I'm working on some Magento 2 extension that requires reading files from the file system.
When running the php sniffer using the ECGM2 standards, it complains about the fact that I'm using functions like `basename` or `dirname`.

> The use of function dirname() is forbidden

or

> The use of function basename() is forbidden

What wrapper should I use instead of those to get the the same effect?

**[EDIT]**
Here is some code, but it's not that relevant to the question.
I have a collection class that extends the `\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Filesystem` class and I want to list this collection in a grid (ui-components) and one of the actions in the grid is a download action.
For this, I need to get the actual name of the file so I can send it to the download action.

```
    // here $file is dynamic and it can be
    // folder/filename.xml or folder/subfolder/file.tar.gz
    //so there is no strict number of folders and subfolders.
    $file = $downloader->getRelativePath($packageName);
    $relativeFile = UmcFilesystem::VAR_DIR_NAME . '/' .$file;
    $absoluteFile = $rootDir->getAbsolutePath($relativeFile);
    if ($rootDir->isFile($relativeFile) && $rootDir->isReadable($relativeFile)){
        //I don't want to use `explode` just for the sake of avoiding basename
        $fileName = basename($absoluteFile);
        $this->fileFactory->create(
            $fileName,
            null,
            DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
            'application/octet-stream',
            $rootDir->stat($relativeFile)['size']
        );

        $resultRaw = $this->resultRawFactory->create();
        $resultRaw->setContents($rootDir->readFile($relativeFile));
        return $resultRaw;
    } else {
       ...
    }
```

Comment: can you share part of your code, what you have try to reading file from system.

Comment: I added some code, but it's totally irrelevant for the question. The question is somehow abstract. what should I use instead of basename so that the code sniffer does not complain?

Comment: Its look like permission issue only.

Comment: It has nothing to do with permissions. The code works properly, but the code sniffer says that  should not use `basename` in there. Please read the question carefully.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I also needed something like that recently. The only solution I found to get `basename` and `dirname` was using:

> \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File

```
protected function someFunction()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File $fileSystemIo **/
    $fileInfo = $this->fileSystemIo->getPathInfo('<absolutePath>');
    $basename = $fileInfo['basename']; 
    $dirname = $fileInfo['dirname'];
}
```

Before that, I tried using `Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write` and `getDriver()` with no success. With them, you can get pretty much everything but not the `basename`.

Comment: YES. That's it. Thank you. I will award the bounty as soon as I am allowed to.

Comment: Marius are you really going to implement it that way? [\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File->getpathinfo][1] literally only calls [pathinfo][2] which in turn calls basename and dirname


  [1]: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filesystem/Io/File.php#L888
  [2]: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/string.c#L1662

Comment: @Richard. I saw that. For now I need/want to avoid certain functions. And in  my specific case it fits nicely because I already had an instance of `\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File` injected in my own class for a different functionality. I just didn't know upfront about the `getPathInfo` method.

Answer (score 3):

Luckily git lets us see when dirname and basename were [forbidden](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/blame/master/Ecg/Sniffs/Security/ForbiddenFunctionSniff.php#L125), the reason is clearly, "Added files"

Looking at the issue for the ECG project you can see closed issues such as [something bad in file_exists? #33](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/issues/33), [Error Functions #26](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/issues/26), [something bad in this functions? #17](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/issues/17), [Context / Explanation for the Rules #12](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/issues/12), [The use of function iconv() is forbidden #14](https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard/issues/14) which would make me think that the initial list of forbidden functions wasn't given too much consideration, and magento are probably amenable to changing the forbidden list.

Searching the [m2 codebase](https://github.com/magento/magento2/search?p=1&q=%22basename%22&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) shows ~= 78 results for basename, a mix of variables and the code actually calling basename, including my [favourite](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/1ade3b769a937f19682bbbe4e51b6c956147952f/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/File.php#L82).

I think if I were you I'd post an issue on github and ask zlik if he still thinks they belong there or if M2 provides a wrapper

Answer (score 2):

You can use object of `SplFileInfo()` class may be it will work.

```
$info = new SplFileInfo('/path/to/foo.txt');
var_dump($info->getFilename())
```

may be it will work.

you can also refer [this](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getfilename.php) url.

Comment: Thanks for this. It looks cleaner, but do you have a code example that does this? I want to follow the core standards.

Comment: you can refer http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getfilename.php this url.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to use the `Magento/Backup` module as an example.

The way the download action class is written would be interesting to look at because it also deals with real files to download:

```
public function execute()
{
    /* @var $backup \Magento\Backup\Model\Backup */
    $backup = $this->_backupModelFactory->create(
        $this->getRequest()->getParam('time'),
        $this->getRequest()->getParam('type')
    );

    if (!$backup->getTime() || !$backup->exists()) {
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('backup/*');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }

    $fileName = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backup\Helper\Data')->generateBackupDownloadName($backup);

    $this->_fileFactory->create(
        $fileName,
        null,
        DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
        'application/octet-stream',
        $backup->getSize()
    );

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw $resultRaw */
    $resultRaw = $this->resultRawFactory->create();
    $resultRaw->setContents($backup->output());
    return $resultRaw;
}
```

To me you should look at the way this method generates the file to download using `\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory` and `generateBackupDownloadName` from `Magento\Backup\Helper\Data` (notice the recommended use of the OM ;) )

### Another interesting bit

Another interesting thing you should look at is the `getStorageData` method from `Magento\MediaStorage\Model\ResourceModel\File\Storage\File` which itself calls directly `dirname` and `basename` but if you call that core method in your module, you won't get the forbidden errors ;)

```
public function getStorageData($dir = '/')
{
    $files = [];
    $directories = [];
    $directoryInstance = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
    if ($directoryInstance->isDirectory($dir)) {
        foreach ($directoryInstance->readRecursively($dir) as $path) {
            $itemName = basename($path);
            if ($itemName == '.svn' || $itemName == '.htaccess') {
                continue;
            }
            if ($directoryInstance->isDirectory($path)) {
                $directories[] = [
                    'name' => $itemName,
                    'path' => dirname($path) == '.' ? '/' : dirname($path),
                ];
            } else {
                $files[] = $path;
            }
        }
    }

    return ['files' => $files, 'directories' => $directories];
}
```

In a similar idea, there's also the `collectFileInfo` from `Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Media`

Comment: `generateBackupDownloadName` uses some magic getters from the backup model. So they must have magic setters called before. I don't see anything related to basename or an alternative to it.

Comment: @Marius see my updated answer for another possible way

Comment: This could work. I will give it a try and come back with the results.

Comment: @Marius also check `collectFileInfo` from `Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Media` ;)

Comment: `collectFileInfo` won't help me because it expects a file inside the media folder. Mine is in in the var folder. Also `getStorageData` has nothing to do with what I need. I don't want to collect all the files in a folder. I already have the file name.

Comment: @marius in that case I suggest you use `Magento/Filesystem/DirectoryInterface` or `Magento/Filesystem/Directory/ReadInterface` as well as `Magento/Filesystem/File/ReadInterface`